# How to append values from series with the same length into an array in a Dataframe column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with two columns containing numbers and another one with empty numpy arrays,
the length of the index is the same

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [101, 200, 306, 402, 500, 600],
    'col2': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600]})
df['col3'] = np.empty((len(df), 0)).tolist()

    #out

   col1  col2 col3
0   101   100   []
1   200   200   []
2   306   300   []
3   402   400   []
4   500   500   []
5   600   600   []
```

I'm trying to append the change between the values to the array in `col3`, but when I do this:

```
df['col3'] = np.append(df['col3'], df['col1'] - df['col2'])

# And:

df2 = pd.Series(df['col1'] - df['col2'])
df['col3'] = np.append(df['col3'], df2)

# And: 

arr = np.where(df['col1'] != df['col2'], df['col1'] - df['col2'], 0)
df['col3'] = np.append(df['col3'], arr)
```

Everything returns the same result:

```
ValueError: Length of values (12) does not match length of index (6)
```

I thought about creating an array outside the dataframe, but I find it problematic because the amount of rows in each column of my Dataframe might change (some will be NA) and since it will treat the array as a 1d array it will just be appending all the values in row instead of preserving the index.

Basically what I'm trying to do is create an array for each row and have them calculating the difference independently of one another.

Is it possible to do this without loops and lambdas?

Comment: Each of those arrays in `col3` is a separate array, not a row of a 2d  array.  Separate arrays, especially if they differ in size, require iteration.  There's any whole-array operation that works on such a list or object dtype Series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subtract col1 and col2 and then convert to numpy:

```
df['col3'] = df['col1'].sub(df['col2']).to_numpy()[:,None].tolist()
```

Or following your method you cannot escape a loop if you are trying to append an existing list/array in pandas since pandas doesnot expect these dtypes in a dataframe. You will need an apply with a lambda on axis=1

```
df['col3'] = df.apply(lambda x: np.append(x['col3'], x['col1'] - x['col2']),axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I know how to do It with a lambda tho, my question was mainly if there's a way to do it and avoid using lambda and loops

Comment: @TomerPoliakov Check the first approach, that is vectorized

Comment: Thanks for your effort! Anything helps, and about wether I can do the appending part without some kind of loop, I guess the answer is no

Comment: @TomerPoliakov Because pandas doesnot expect lists/dicts/arrays in cells the answer is no. You would have to either resort to apply and lambda which is a loop or create one from scratch.

Comment: you could add it to the answer since it answers my question on how to do it, Thanks again for the help, I appreciate it a lot!